# JavaScript clearInterval only works once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I just learned this so I'll try to explain it as clearly as possible.

I have a function that loops. What I'd like to accomplish is when something is hovered over the loop stops, then starts again when the cursor leaves. This seems to work correctly, but if I hover, leave, then hover again the animation keeps looping. The worst thing is that if I mouse-in/out two times the loop interval gets updated so it loops twice during the set time.

Anyway, this is my code I'm working with:

```
var transition_delay = "3000";

function next_image(){
    var current_eq = $('ul#triggers li.current_trigger').index();

    if (current_eq == li_count) { //if this is the last image in the array
        $triggers.removeClass("current_trigger").eq(0).addClass("current_trigger"); //removes current and adds it to next
        $displays.fadeOut("slow").eq(0).fadeIn("slow"); //fades out then in next display
    }
    else { //if not last image
        $triggers.removeClass("current_trigger").eq(current_eq + 1).addClass("current_trigger"); //removes current class and adds it to next
        $displays.fadeOut("slow").eq(current_eq + 1).fadeIn("slow"); //fades out then next display in
    }
};

$triggers.hover(
    function(){ //in
        console.log("clearing");
        clearInterval(next_image_interval);
    },
    function(){ //out
        console.log("starting");
        sliderIntervalID = setInterval(function(){next_image();},,transition_delay);
});

next_image_interval = setInterval(function(){
next_image();
}, transition_delay);
```

Comment: What's with the double comma in the hover-out handler (right before `transition_delay`)...?

Comment: `sliderIntervalID = setInterval` may be `next_image_interval`??

Comment: BTW, just so it's said, `function(){next_image();}` can be replaced with `nextImage` here (eg: `setInterval(next_image, transition_delay);`).  The `function` wrapping is good for calling a bunch of stuff and/or extending scope and such, but isn't needed here (where all you're doing is calling one function).

Answer (score 2):

In hover-out, you are doing this:

```
sliderIntervalID = setInterval(function(){next_image();},,transition_delay);
```

but you are clearing:

```
clearInterval(next_image_interval);
```

Change `sliderIntervalID` to `next_image_interval`, should work as expected.

Comment: cHao: Just a typo, thats not in my actual code, oddly enough. I'm not sure how that got in there.

icyrock: That worked perfectly, thanks! This is the first time i've attempted looping anything, so you have been a great help.